# how to compare two date in the format "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have two dates 06-05-2016 13:05 and 13-05-2016 13:05. I want to compare these two date in java script.
I tried

```
var dateFrom = Date.parse('06-05-2016 13:05');
alert(dateFrom);
var dateTo = Date.parse('13-05-2016 13:05'); 
alert(dateFrom);
if (dateFrom > dateTo) {        
    return false;
}
```

but it always return false.

Comment: if you working with dates a lot you can use moment.js

Comment: You have to use another format for you date string. Instead of "dd-MM-yyyy" use "yyyy-MM-dd" then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

it's working properly here. Make sure you're using returns inside a function.

```js
function test(a, b){
 var dateFrom = Date.parse(a);
 var dateTo = Date.parse(b);
 if ( dateFrom > dateTo ) {
  console.log( a, ' > ',b );
  return false;
 }
 console.log( a, ' <= ', b );
 return true;
}
var result = test('06-05-2016 13:05', '13-05-2016 13:05');
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =  result;
console.log( result )
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>
```